# Spotfire - filters applied to be saved in DB

Tags: spotfire

How to store user actions like which filter was applied on a table 'xyz' by which user in spotfire?? and this action performed by user must be stored in a database log

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Take a look at this post to help you craft a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you'd want to log that. You are serving up data to users. Why would you care how they sliced and diced it?  Regardless, here is where you want to start:

[Tibco Spotfire Server and Environement Action logs and system monitoring](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.1/doc/html/tsas_admin_help/GUID-6083CDAB-E023-4144-A65E-3559706FBA3A.html)

Comment: We want to serve them better..... we want to know what the users are actually doing......

Comment: Well, I would just ask them. I'm still unsure of how you would server them better by identifying the filters they apply. You can enable book marks and personalized views to allow them to save / return to where they left off.

Comment: if you of any other way then do post here

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense to me